# How to limit which files should be shown in OpenFileDialog?

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I used information from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

this way:

```
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

 dlg.DefaultExt = ".xml"; // this is how I get only required extension 
 dlg.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml"; // I guess, this should be modified, don't know how.
dlg.InitialDirectory = _directoryName1;
// here we go
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                string path = dlg.FileName;
```

In the Initial Directory I have to types of files of same `xml` extension, which names begin with `script-Data...` or `GeneralParam...`. So I need to show in the OpenFileDialog only files, which names begin with `script-Data...`.

I know, that I can notify user, what he has decided wrong file by parsing `path`, but it isn't good solution for me. Is any other way out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have already set the `Filter` property. so you can see only `.xml` files when `OpenFileDialog` opens. but if you want to `filter` the `filenames` to be displayed in `OpenFileDialog` you can set the `FileName` property as there is no other option to `filter` by `filename`

Try This:

```
dlg.FileName = "script-Data*";
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this.it will help you.if you want to filter file name starting with "script-Data" only sho in your application do this.

```
OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
of.Filter = "Excel Files|script-Data*.xls;ascript-Data*.xlsx;script-Data*.xlsm";
of.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can prepare your OpenFileDialog with the predefined settings expected,  but 
you can't prevent your user to type something totally different in the inputbox from the pattern expected. For example, if your user types `"*.*"` in the input box and presses OK he/she can choose any file showed, but you could check what has been choosed **WITHOUT EXITING** the `OpenFileDialog` and inform your user of the error.

All you need to do is to subscribe to the event `FileOk`

```
OpenFile dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
dlg.FileOk += CheckFileName;
dlg.InitialDirectory = _directoryName1;
dlg.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
dlg.FileName = "script-data*";
if(sdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("Open file:" + sdlg.FileName);
    ..... 
}   



  void CheckFileName(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
  {
      OpenFileDialog dlg = (sender as OpenFileDialog);
      if(Path.GetExtension(dlg.FileName).ToLower() != ".xml")
      {
          e.Cancel = true;
          MessageBox.Show("Please choose files with the extension 'XML'");
          return;
      }
      if(!Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName).ToLower().StartsWith("script-data")
      {
          e.Cancel = true;
          MessageBox.Show("Please choose files that starts with 'script-data'");
          return;
      }
   }
```